# Laravel eloquent query with multiple child relations

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am working on a query but can't find the solution to this one.

The structure i have at the moment is:

A project has 1 machine, but a machine can belong to multiple projects.
A machine can have multiple issues.

Now i want to get all projects with the issues created after the project got created.

The query that i have at the moment, but doesn't work:

```
        $allProjects = Project::with(['machine',
        'machine.issues' => function ($query) {
                $query->where('created_at', '>=', 'project.created_at');
            }
        ])
        ->orderBy('id')
        ->get();
```

I am not getting the issues at all by using this query, when i switch the operator to: < then i get all the issues even the ones after project.created_at

Comment: Can you provide the laravel version you are running?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a pivot do most of the work for you. I tried reproducing your problem statement as below.

```php
 <?php

 class Project extends Model
 {
    use HasFactory;

    public function machine()
    {
       return $this->hasOneThrough(Machine::class, MachineProject::class, 'machine_id', 'id', 'id', 'project_id');
    }

    public function issues()
    {
       return $this->hasManyThrough(Issue::class, Machine::class, 'id', 'machine_id')->whereDate('issues.created_at', '<=', $this->created_at);
    }
}


class Machine extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public $with = ['issues'];

    public function projects()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Project::class);
    }

    public function issues()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Issue::class);
    }
}


class Issue extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function machine()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Machine::class);
    }
}


class MachineProject extends Pivot
{
    //
}
```

To retrieve the Project with issues, you just do

```php
$allProjects = Project::with(['machine' => function ($machine) {
    $machine->with('issues');
}])->get();
```

Comment: At the moment i can get the projects with all the machine issues, but i only need to get issues with created_at >= project->created_at

Comment: @LesleyPeters You can achieve this on the model easily. I updated the answer. Check the issues method on the Project model.